# Angular ng-model not binding to select

Tags: angularjs

I'm pulling a list of accounts from my data base, and using that info to make a select drop down with the name showing, and id as the value. That all works fine, however, once I try to send it to my controller to be posted to my API, there's no to or from accounts. I have the ng-model on both fields, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's my HTML

```
    <form novalidate>
    <div ng-controller="newTransactionController">
         <div >
             <label for="from">From Account</label>
             <select name="from" ng-options="acct as acct.label for acct in options" ng-model="transaction.fromAccount" > 
                <option value="acct.value"> </option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="to">To Account</label>
            <select name="to">
                <option ng-repeat="account in accounts" value="{%account._id%}" ng-model="transaction.toAccount">{%account.name%}</option> 
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
         <label for="amount">Amount</label>
         <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="" tabindex="1" ng-model="transaction.amount"/>
    </div>

   <div>
        <label for="currency">Currency</label>
        <select name="currency" ng-model="transaction.currency">
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
            <option value="BTC">BTC</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
         <label for="interval">Interval</label>
         <input type="text" name="interval" id="interval" value="" tabindex="1" ng-model="transaction.interval"/>
    </div>

   <div>
         <label for="processDate">Process Date</label>
         <input type="text" name="processDate" id="processDate" value="" tabindex="1" ng-model="transaction.processDate"/>
    </div>

  <div>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Send" ng-click="createTransaction(transaction)"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my controller

```
    $http.get('').success(function(data){
    $scope.accounts = data;
    var options = $scope.options = [];

    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        $scope.options.push({label: data[i].name, value: data[i]._id});
    }
});

$scope.createTransaction = function(transaction){

    var transactions = {
         fromAccount: angular.copy(transaction.fromAccount),
         toAccount: angular.copy(transaction.toAccount),
         amount: angular.copy(transaction.amount),
         currency: angular.copy(transaction.currency),
         interval: angular.copy(transaction.interval),
         processDate: angular.copy(transaction.processDate)
    };


    $http.post('', transactions).success(function(){console.log('sent')});
};
```

When I log out transactions in the controller, all I get is: Object {amount: "1", currency: "USD"}

I'm lost. I can't figure out what's missing here.

Comment: You should post an answer to your own Question instead of editing the question.

Comment: I'll add the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. It was a scope issue with the `<div>` tag surrounding both of the `to` and `from` accounts.